# biulding tor relay

Tags: relays, help, circuit

i dont know someone else asking this before but bere is my quetion

if i had biuld tor relay to help network
obviously the network will quickly biuld circut on it

i wana put huge bandwidth on it
its ok tor use my bandwideth

but can i hold some of it for my own?

for instans 100gbit band witdth
can i let tor use 50 % of it and rest will be mine to use?

is there someway go control it?

tnx for answering

Answer (score 0):

Tor relays have the `BandwidthRate` and `BandwidthBurst` torrc options to restrict the rate of Tor traffic. You can use these to limit the Tor traffic to an average of 500 Mbps for example.

There's also `AccountingMax` if you need to limit the amount of traffic in a day, month, or week (for example if your ISP only allows a certain amount of traffic per month).